# About how Intercepts are expressed.

Tags: geometry

I was recently docked points in Math due to what I'll explain, and I would like to know if it is valid.

According to my teacher, intercepts are supposed to be a value. For example, the y intercept of y=x-2 is -2. However, I am wondering if (0,-2) cannot be qualified as a valid answer. The value of the intercept has been expressed in the coordinate, and I even expressed the point in the quadrant. The quadrant is supposed to represent the values from what I know.

I understand where the teacher is coming from, but I'm curious if I'm completely wrong.

Comment: Not completely wrong, but yeah "intercepts" represent the length, not the coordinate, which is the "point of intersection".

Comment: I'm not too familiar with English terminology, I apologize for my misuse. Also, thanks for the answer.